# How to access the correct `this` inside a callback for AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am unable to access `this` in callback function but i end up using `this` pointing to AJAX object rather than `this` object who invoked `onClickEmail` function. I tried getting the reference in `that` variable but that didn't helped much either.

Anything I am doing wrong here:

```
onClickEmail() {
  var that = this;
  var hey = "xyz" 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/test123/tweets'
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(hey);
    console.log(that);
  });
}
```

More than solving the problem, I would like to know why is it that I can read value of `hey` variable but `that` is undefined

Comment: If I could understand what you wanted to use 'this' for, I may be of more help.

Comment: I am creating a web app using emberjs. this method `onClickEmail ` is invoked on clicking a DOM element. the class that owns this 'onClickEmail' method has some attributes that i would need to access as soon as i get a AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

this - the variable refers to object that owns the function.
Use **bind** or try it

```
var that = this;
onClickEmail(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/test123/tweets'
        }).then(function(response) {
            hey = that;
        });
}
```

Comment: I am getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: that is not defined" error when I try to access "that"

Comment: It's hard to tell having no full code. What are you want to put in "that"?

Comment: Here is the full code: https://github.com/cravi24/clientAppEmber/blob/master/app/controllers/home.js

Comment: What are you want to get from 'this' variable? Model? DOM element?

Comment: you can get model this.get('model') or send in parameter
add model in
{{email-list email=emailUnit onClickEmail=(action "onClickEmail" emailUnit)}}
and add param in controller onClickEmail: function(email)

Comment: I am nt trying to read anything from DOM. Rather i would like to initiate an action as soon as this method is invoked. Problem is the object on which i have to invoke action lies with `this`